# what's wrong with having post-increment within a block

Tags: ruby

Here's the code that triggers the error:

```
#!/home/yuri/.rbenv/shims/ruby
a = []
a += [1, 2, 3].map { |v|
    v++
}
```

And here's what it says:

```
/home/yuri/_/1.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '}'
```

And this one runs without errors:

```
#!/home/yuri/.rbenv/shims/ruby
a = []
a += [1, 2, 3].map { |v|
    v++
    v
}
```

But then this doesn't:

```
#!/home/yuri/.rbenv/shims/ruby
a = []
a += [1, 2, 3].map { |v|
    v++ if false
    v
}
```

The output:

```
/home/yuri/_/1.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

Is there a way to explain this behavior? Or at least, how to avoid it? I'm running `ruby-2.0`, if anything.

Comment: `[1,2,3].each {|v| v += 99; print "#{v} "} => 100 101 102`.  This should tell you what is happening when you attempt to manipulate the iterator variable (something you should not do).

Comment: @Cary Swoveland I don't seem to get the message. The output is as expected. Why shouldn't I do this?

Comment: All variables local to a block, including the iterator variable, have a life that ends when the block is exited; i.e., after each iteration.  While there is nothing incorrect in what you are doing, I think there are a couple of reasons it generally is not done. #1: often there is no advantage to modifying the interator variable. In your example, `[1, 2, 3].map {|v| v + 1}` is simpler than `[1, 2, 3].map {|v| v += 1; v}`. #2, someone else reading your code may be confused if they misunderstand the scoping rules.  You may find @JLR's answer to so question 1654637 helpful.

Comment: I suppose changing iterator variable may be occasionally advantageous. When you're using the changed value several times later within the block, for instance.

Comment: I would instead use another local variable, e.g., `a.each {|i| e = i**2; ...use e here...}`.  Note that the iterator variable is not a "deep copy", so in some cases you can cause problems by modifying its value.  For example, if `a = [[1,2]]` and we execute `a.each {|e| e[0] += 1}`, then `a => [[2, 2]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby has no post-increment operator.

Following statement

```
v++
v
```

is equivalent to

```
v + (+v)
```

---

Use `v += 1` instead. (It's not an post-increment as you may know.)